# Composer can't install Larasponse

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to use Fractal with Laravel to create an API. I'm following [this](https://laravelista.com/posts/laravel-fractal)  tutorial, but once I run composer update, the following error appear:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>   Class 'Sorskod\Larasponse\LarasponseServiceProvider' not found
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump
>   event returned with error code 1

Does someone knows how to solve hist?

In my composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "^1.5",
        "sorskod/larasponse": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "sorskod/larasponse": "~1.0"
    },
```

Comment: The tutorial you are following is written for Laravel 4.2 The author presumed that his code would work for future Laravel releases, but there are no such guarantees. Have you tried the implicit data binding and api resources to build an api in Laravel 5.5? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources

Comment: Thanks @sisve, i'm searching a way to paginate on an api and also rename database fields, this way the api won't show my database structure.